# How can we map the degree in between two points on an image IN matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, angle

We know the center point of an image (say X0, Y0) and also know the observed point coordinates (say X, Y). Then we have to calculate the degree of that point (X, Y) and also the direction of that point. Finally we have to convert it into the value of compass angle. [image]

Comment: It would be better if you provided an example with real values rather than a theoretical...

Comment: This is basic trigonometry. Start by working out how you'd do it on paper. Then writing the code should be easy.

Comment: As you work out the problem on paper, you will probably come across the arctan function. Restist the temptation to use Matlab's `atan(y/x)` and instead go for `atan2(y,x)` - this will ensure you get all 360° (or 2*pi) as possible answers.

Comment: How do you quantify the direction of the point?  Do you simply look at the difference between each `x` and `y` coordinate pair?